# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>!

Tags: android, infinite-scroll, android-inflate

This is the method that can display the errors.

The error :

Caused by:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

this code below ,

```
.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
```

display the error..

and this is the onCreateViewHolder which has an error.

```
    @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }
    else if ( viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
        return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and this is the item.layout xml codes!
I thought this xml file is related to an error. so I posted this. thanks!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
app:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLength"
    android:text="length"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you update your question with code for `getItemViewType` method in you RecyclerView.Adapter?

Comment: you need to handle default case also. May be `onCreateViewHolder` return null

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question it seems like you have issue with your `getItemViewType` method in `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

The default implementation of this method returns 0, making the assumption of a single view type for the adapter. Since you are expecting different view type ensure you have overridden this method judiciously.

If you haven't implemented `getItemViewType` then your `onCreateViewHolder` will always return null ViewHolder since it will never match to your `VIEW_TYPE_ITEM` & `VIEW_TYPE_LOADING`. The solution would be to correctly Override `getItemViewType`and return appropriate View type.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    final boolean shouldShowTypeItem = <your conditional statement>;
    return shouldShowTypeItem ? VIEW_TYPE_ITEM : VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
}
```